# One hidden input vs 1000 hidden input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have approximately 1000 hidden inputs to send to laravel. I think I have 2 options to send those inputs.

**Option 1 :**

I make 1000 hidden input and send them to laravel.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[1]" value="some stuff">
<input type="hidden" name="id[1]" value="some stuff">
..
<input type="hidden" name="id[100]" value="some stuff">
```

**Option 2 :**

I make only 1 hidden input as a JSON object which contains all other hidden inputs .

```
<input type="hidden name="value" value="A_JSON_OBJECT">
```

By the way I may send the form with Ajax.
My question is which one can be faster?

Comment: Use array notation instead `name="id[]"`..

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Thank you for your interest. What do you mean specifically?

Comment: You aren't going to get any performance difference since the same amount of data will be captured and sent either way. But, clearly sending one object as opposed to gathering up 1000 is a better design approach.

Comment: Use the array, in my opinion, sending them as separated fields could take more processing time.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks sir. Another question, Is there any way to send jquery sessionStorage to php file?

Comment: Of course. Just get the data out of `sessionStorage` and include it in the data being sent to .php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean you could use the array notation `[]` in the name of all the fields so you will receive an array in the server-side, e.g :

```
//Same name for all the fields
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="some stuff">
```

Then send the data to your server-side script using ajax request like :

```
$.post('file.php', $('input[name="id[]"]').serialize(), function(response){
    //Server response
});
```

In your `file.php` you recieve the data in `$_POST['id'];` as array.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating 1000 HTML elements, sure browsers will handle it, but it can be surprisingly heavyweight.

The POST data would also be verbosely translated to:

```
id%5B%5D=Some+stuff&id%5B%5D=Some+stuff&id%5B%5D=Some+stuff&id%5B%5D=Some+stuff...
```

Which is a repetition of `&id%5B%5D=` for every element.  That's 10K of separators for 1000 items, probably 9K bigger than it needs to be (or ~7K bigger than if using a JSON-encoded array in a single field value).